# MySQL Trigger Update

Tags: mysql, trigger

How do I update 'emailupdate' date with a trigger when 'email' is updated through a script?

```
+------+----------------+--------------+
|  id  |      email     | emailupdate  |
+------+----------------+--------------+
|  1   | email@mail.com |  2015-08-10  |
+------+----------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a trigger - they extend transaction processing time, are difficult to debug if you have issues, cause deadlocks, etc.

Update the `emailupdate` in the same statement as you are updating the email.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET email = 'testemail@gmail.com', 
    emailupdate = curdate() 
WHERE email = 'PreviousEmail@aol.com';
```

With that being said, if there is no other option than to create a trigger, syntax like this may be helpful:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateEmail
BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.emailupdate = curdate();
```

Comment: To me a trigger seems ideal exactly for this kind of simple jobs.

Comment: Here is a really good discussion with many perspectives on triggers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460316/are-database-triggers-evil
I have worked on projects to redesign apps which relied to heavily on triggers and though they are very rarely necessary, if you can get away with not using them, you are usually better off.  In this situation, why not just add the update date to the script which is updating the email?

Comment: relied TOO heavily - oops!